# Error: Can't assign to the final variable 'color'. assert(color = null || decoration == null, ^^^^^

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I can't run even a simple code. I think the problem is with the container. dart
[image: this is first picture]

This is the full picture in debug console. I am doing flutter for 1 month. Can someone help me out?
[image: This is second Picture]

Comment: don't know much regarding flutter, but the color conditional is missing a '=' I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you've corrupted your Flutter install. That line 274 is meant to say `color == null` not `color = null`

```
   assert(color == null || decoration == null,
     'Cannot provide both a color and a decoration\n'
     'To provide both, use "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)".',
   ),
```

You can just correct that back, but you may want to remove and reinstall Flutter, just in case there are other corruptions.